# Can't create new Liferay plugin in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, liferay, liferay-6, eclipse-kepler, liferay-ide

I use eclipse kepler, Liferay IDE with the Liferay sdk 7 and V6.1 CE server.
When I try to make new plugin from the wizard this error occurs:

> The selected wizard could not be started. Plug-in
>   "com.liferay.ide.project.ui" was unable to instantiate class
>   "com.liferay.ide.project.ui.wizard.NewLiferayPluginProjectWizard".
>   Could not initialize class
>   com.liferay.ide.project.core.model.NewLiferayPluginProjectOp

anybody had this issue before? thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using Liferay 6.1 CE you must use the Plugin SDK 6.1 as well, you can't use the one from version 7.

That, and please note that 6.1 doesn't get any more updates for quite a long time - so one could also argue that instead of downgrading the SDK, you should upgrade the server to Liferay 7. When you do this, note that the Plugins SDK is deprecated in favor of Liferay Workspace.

Comment: now I have SDK 6.2 and V6.2 CE server and still same problem, is that because of the Liferay IDE version?

Comment: I am sorry about that, it is 2 and failed so many times to upgrade it to 3

Comment: I've changed this question's tags to include liferay-ide to summon the wizards